# Will Ubuntu 16.04 have support for Win 10 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, 16.04

As the title mentions, I just want to know if Ubuntu 16.04 will support dual boot installation alongside a previously installed Windows 10.

When I was trying to install ubuntu 15.10 the option of "Install ubuntu alongside windows" was not there, which makes me think that maybe windows changed something in the structure of its file system, or the MBR or something else (I haven't research that in depth), I also know that my case is not unique, some others of my friends have told me about this.

This because I have A LOT of problems (as I haven't had in years) to install Ubuntu 15.10 in [my computer](https://gaming.msi.com/products/notebook/ge-series?id=MzU0MQ==) (link just in case it matters) alongside the installed windows 10.

If this extension to that feature is going to be present can someone point me to the reference from where I can get that information so that in the future I do not need to create another question.

Comment: All Ubuntu versions support dual boot with Win 10. You'd better describe your problem more precise and find a solution. You may have some specific problem.

Comment: I had no trouble making 15.10 dual boot with Windows 10. I made secure boot and fast boot to be disabled in BIOS

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable FastBoot in Windows 10. It locks system partition making Ubuntu unable to recognise it.

Comment: @Cams As an alternative, you can add 'remove_hiberfile' to the mount options of the NTFS volume so that Linux will remove hibefil.sys. In Windows 8 and onwards, by default if you shut down, rather than shutting down fully, it basically partially hibernates itself so it can start faster next time. I'd recommend doing this if you don't use Ubuntu as much and could benefit from this behavior (only removing the hiberfil when you need to access the disk from Ubuntu), but if you use Ubuntu a lot, creating the hiberfil just to remove it is useless, so I'd disable fast boot.